# Docker GCE, Layer already being pulled by another client. Waiting

Tags: docker, docker-compose, drone.io, google-compute-engine

I am using Docker container for drone on GCE, and I have a issue that I cannot docker image from my GCP repository. Here is last logs of drone.io.

```
Pulling repository asia.gcr.io/lesson-mothership/gojayui
953e0520a10f: Layer already being pulled by another client. Waiting.
```

---

I tried to fix this, so I run those code to restart docker container.

```
sudo service docker restart
docker-compose start
```

It does not work, and I run also:

```
docker restart 63090e5250aa ( <- container ID )
```

---

I do not have any idea any more, here is information about my environment of GCE for drone.

```
developer@ltd-drone:~$ docker-compose version
docker-compose version 1.7.1, build 6c29830
docker-py version: 1.8.1
CPython version: 2.7.12
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
```

I really appreciate if there is someone who know how to fix this issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the way to solve this problem, that was storage problem of drone GCE so drone could not install JAVA when it has to build docker image. What I did is removing docker images and container that I do not use anymore.